# How to deliver .m4v as .mp4 for Firefox

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is there a way to deliver 'movie.m4v' as 'movie.mp4' to Firefox 21? I already figured out how to sniff FF21 with PHP and let it put 'movie.mp4' as additional source in the video element (HTML 5) and tried a simple mod-rewrite with replacing the suffix. But it didn't work. Is there a way of changing the suffix in the htaccess without FF noticing it? Sending the very same m4v-file with a mp4-suffix?

(Mozilla forgot to add the suffix .m4v (like it happended to iOS two years ago; Apple fixed it within two days after I reported it) or omitted it on purpose, because it is only common and not in the spec.)

Thanks, Runa

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your .htaccess file or Apache config has [a line like](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/8f743702f6846a3fff86da56ea69c1f4e07d161b/.htaccess#L144):

```
AddType video/mp4    mp4 m4v f4v f4p
```

Firefox doesn't care about the file extension, it cares what content type is being set by the server in the HTTP headers, it's the server which cares about the file extension.

Comment: I'm afraid, it does. AddType is set correctly. The HTTP Header Content Type changes with the suffix. I use clones of the same file, one with .mp4 and the other one with .m4v.

Comment: When I open movie.mp4 in FF locally from my harddrive, it'll be displayed natively. After renaming it into movie.m4v it will be displayed in the QT-Plugin. I checked this with different files made by different encoders.

That's why I come to think that the suffix matters. Changing it changes behaviour.

Comment: BUT: Though FF21 can play the mp4-file natively from disk, it cannot play its copy from the server, neither alone nor embedded in the video-element as only source.

All my files and configurations work pretty well in Chrome, IE10 and iOS, I thought I could get rid of gigabytes of Ogg-Theora double content.

Comment: @user2240646 Changing it on disk matters because on disk the content type comes from the operating system, when you play it from the server the content type comes from the server.  Use a network inspector and confirm the content type is what you think it is.